# Woocommerce, PHP 7.2 Function create_function() is deprecated

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When i activate Woocommerce plugin website giving 500 server error. I've activate debug mode.

PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/WEBSITENAME/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/features-by-woothemes/classes/class-woothemes-widget-features.php on line 308

That's 308 line:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'return register_widget("WooThemes_Widget_Features");' ), 1 );
```

How to fix it???

Comment: There are a few solutions which pop up when you google your exact title, none really having much of a "out of the box solution". So try to upgrade your Woocommerce. This might be one of those rare cases where you temporary surpress the error.

Comment: @Martijn I have upgraded Woocommerce it doesn't help

Comment: This might help: [Function create_function() is Deprecated in PHP 7.2 - How to Migrate?](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/12/17/function-create-function-is-deprecated-in-php-72-how-to-migrate/)

Answer (score 1):

just replace the mentioned line with:

```
add_action( 
    'widgets_init', 
    function () { 
        return register_widget("WooThemes_Widget_Features");
    }, 
    1 
);
```

OH and by the way, if that works, please prepare a PR with the fix in:
https://github.com/woocommerce/features/pulls
then contact the author on 
https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/features-by-woothemes
to merge it in

Comment: it's not worked :C debug repeat Function create_function() is deprecated in  308 line

Comment: this is wrong, you have just removed create function with my code replacement. Either you're telling me about different code place (the error should mention excat place - maybe there are more calls to `create_function` in the plugin?), or you didn't replace the code at line 308.